# Relação entre entidades retorna null

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Estou tendo dificuldade para verificar um parametro em uma relação entre as entiades Historico e Login.

```
public class Historico {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Login login{ get; set; }
    public DateTime inicio { get; set; }
    public DateTime final { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Login
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        private string Senha { get; set; }
    }
```

Pois sempre que faço consulta no banco de dados, no campo Login retorna nulo.
Queria saber qual a modificação tem que ser para que eu consiga retorna o login ao fazer acesso com o banco de dados.

Comment: Acho que falta decorar os IDs [Key]. Vc está dizendo ao EntityFramework qual o chave das entidades?

Comment: Outro ponto a verificar é o fato de Login ser abstract. Existem, de fato, classes concretas de Login para "realizar" essa relação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por ser um parametro virtual e a classe abstrata pode está afetando o seu resultado.

1. Retirar o abstract da classe.
2. Quando tem o virtual, se vc estiver trabalhando com entity, poderá usar o FluentApi(http://netcoders.com.br/blog/mapeamento-com-entity-framework-code-first-fluent-api-parte-1/) ai sim vc terá as informações do usuário.